# Is “rien n'est à craindre, tout est à comprendre” a play on words?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

A question based on [comments here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31234/did-marie-curie-say-nothing-in-life-is-to-be-feared-its-only-to-be-understood)

> Dans la vie, rien n'est à craindre, tout est à comprendre
>   (Marie Curie)

Is it a play on words in French?

Comment: Long answer: No

Comment: Where would there be a play on word ?

Answer (score 1):

Non, c'est une réflexion philosophique et scientifique d'une femme forte qui a affronté sans peur la vie et a passé tout son temps à essayer de la comprendre, particulièrement au travers de la science.

En français, on ne peut pas jouer avec les mots *craindre* et *comprendre* : même s'ils sont du troisième groupe tous les deux, ils n'ont aucune acception ou connotation communes.

Answer (score 0):

Only a rhetoric figure, but no hidden meaning with sounds